# Airy differential equation $y''+(x-\frac14)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''+(x-\frac14)y=0$
this is the equation I am trying to solve
mathematica tells me the answer is:

$$\left.c_1 \text{Ai}\left(-\sqrt[3]{-1} \left(\frac{1}{4}-x\right)\right)+c_2 \text{Bi}\left(-\sqrt[3]{-1} \left(\frac{1}{4}-x\right)\right)\right]$$

how do I get this result. I don't know how I would end up with $\sqrt[3]{-1}$ in the argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Ai(x)$ and $Bi(x)$ are solutions to the differential equation:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-xy=0$

Obviously, this is different from the form given above.

Thus, let $(x-\frac{1}{4})=-t$

We now have,

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-ty=0$

We have, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}=-\frac{dy}{dt}$

Thus, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\cdot -1=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$

We now have,

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-ty=0$

This is exactly the needed form.

Writing the solution as a function of $t$, we have

$y=c_1Ai(t)+c_2Bi(t)$

But now, setting $t$ in terms of $x$, we have

$y=c_1Ai(\frac{1}{4}-x)+c_2Bi(\frac{1}{4}-x)$

As you can also see, $-\sqrt[3]{-1}=1$ which is the same as the above.

As for Mathematica bringing it up in such a form, I believe it is due to the manipulations given above. When it set $t$ in terms of $x$ and ended up calculating the first and second derivatives in terms of $t$, then set $t$ in terms of $x$ back in the solution, the $-\sqrt[3]{-1}$ came up. You do not have to be bothered with it. It's because of its mechanical nature.

Comment: I forgot to say, but if you want to see why it puts stuff like that, try putting $y''+cxy=0$ for example where $c$ is a constant. You'll end up seeing it pretty clearly.

Comment: that was the answer I arrived at myself. but mathematica's answer made me doubt myself.

Comment: Yeah, it's because it acts according to certain algorithms, rather than how we work. I guess it forgot to simplify or something, or it's just that it's has the general form and it just plugged the needed constants in.

Answer (score 0):

The [Airy functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) $\operatorname{Ai}$ and $\operatorname{Bi}$ are two fundamental solutions of the differential equation:
$$ y'' = x y \tag{1}$$
and they can be represented by the integrals:
$$ \operatorname{Ai}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)\,dx, $$

$$ \operatorname{Bi}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)+\sin\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)\,dx, \tag{2}$$
so they are entire functions on the complex plane having [non-integer order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_3.2F2), $\frac{3}{2}$.

The solutions of your differential equation can be derived from $(1)$ with the change of variable $\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\omega z$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity.